# insertar datos con el tilde ' en MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

Tengo una BD en MySQL, donde inserto datos sacados de SQL server mediante PHP. Todo iba perfecto, hasta que ingreso un dato donde el apellido tiene el tilde `'` .

He probado muchas formas, agregando a mi PHP

```
mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'UTF8');
```

cambiando la colocación, probando diferentes UTF, leí que uno lo puso en latin1. Pero ninguno resulta.

Tengo este INSERT en PHP:

```
         $queryInsert1 = "INSERT INTO `factlog_comedor`(`ID`, `panelName`, 
         `readerID`, `tarjeta`, `apellido`, `nombre`, `descripcion`)VALUE ('$id4', 
         '$panelName4', '$readerID4', '$tarjeta4', '$apellido4', '$nombre4', 
         '$descripcion4')";
    
                    mysqli_query($conn,$queryInsert1);
                
                    echo "<p style='color:green;'>INSERTADO CORRECTAMENTE (FOR)</p>";
```

Ese es el INSERT a MySQL.

Y este es el SELECT que hago en SQL Server.

```
  $querySQLSRV="SELECT TOP 1
        ID,
        panelName,
        readerID,
        tarjeta,
        apellido, 
        nombre, 
        descripcion

    from Factlog_Comedor
    order by ID desc";

$resuestaSQLSRV=sqlsrv_query($con,$querySQLSRV);
```

No sé qué más intentar para que me inserte ese dato con el tilde este `'` .
Si alguien pudiera ayudarme os agradeceré!

**EDIT**

Vale, cambie como me indicaron abajo, en las variables con datos de SQL

```
$apellido4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($row4[4]);
```

En pantalla me muestra este error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 arguments, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Gestion_de_Comedores\Comedores_Totales\NQN-GNOC\traspaso.php:171 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Gestion_de_Comedores\Comedores_Totales\NQN-GNOC\traspaso.php(171): mysqli_real_escape_string('D'AURO') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Gestion_de_Comedores\Comedores_Totales\NQN-GNOC\traspaso.php on line 171

Aclaro la Lina 171 es donde se encuentra la variable

Comment: Usa una [*Sentencia Preparada*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Debes explicar mejor el error, ahora solo se que quieres inertar tildes, pero no que error esta dandote.

Comment: ¿Tilde `á, é...` o comilla simple `'`?

Comment: El apellido es: D'Auro, esas comillas, mysql no me las reconoce.. ahora voy a probar las respuestas que me dieron y comentare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error que tienes con `mysqli_real_escape_string` es porque, como estás usando la forma procedual de mysqli, debes especificar en el primer argumento la conexión:

```php
$apellido4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row4[4]);
```

También podrías usar sentencias preparadas (forma procedual):

```php
$queryInsert1 = "INSERT INTO `factlog_comedor`(`ID`, `panelName`, 
`readerID`, `tarjeta`, `apellido`, `nombre`, `descripcion`) 
VALUE (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $queryInsert1);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssssss", $id4, $panelName4, 
$readerID4, $tarjeta4, $apellido4, $nombre4, $descripcion4);

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Comment: Gracias genio, me sirvio la query de esa forma.

Answer (score 1):

Has intentado cambiar la codificación de tu BBDD en el gestor de bases de datos, yo suelo utilizar al crear mis bases de datos `utf8_general_ci` ese me permite colocar todos los caracteres (acentos, caracteres especiales, etc), pero debes colocarlo directamente en la codificación de tu BBDD.

En MySQL solo debes entrar a tu BBDD, dar click en el botón de `Operaciones`, y en la sección de `cotejamiento` cambiarlo a `utf8_general_ci`, debes seleccionar el check que dice que se modifique el cotejamiento en todas las tablas

Comment: Si no está definido específicamente el cotejamiento, [se recomienda](https://www.google.com/search?q=utf8+utf8mb4) usar **utf8mb4** ya que *uft8* está limitado en cuanto al juego de caracteres. Puedes usar **utf8mb4_general_ci** o **utf8mb4_unicode_ci**.

Answer (score 1):

Ten en cuenta que cada campo que insertas en tu sentencia SQL ya incluye comillas simples, es bastante probable que el problema pueda venir de ahí.

La solución sería *escapar* esas comillas simples de los nombres poniéndoles antes un `\` (por ejemplo, el string `O'Connor` quedaría como `O\'Connor`). Podrías hacerlo con `mysqli_real_escape_string()` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), incluyéndolo antes de tu sentencia SQL:

```
$apellido4    = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $apellido4);
$nombre4      = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $nombre4);
$descripcion4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $descripcion4);
```

En cualquier caso, te recomendaría que tuvieses en cuenta que, por razones de seguridad (evitar inyecciones SQL, ataques XSS...), tengas cuidado con las consultas SQL a las que le pasas variables. Tienes mucha información al respecto, pero aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo hacer consultas de forma segura: https://devlaz.com/consultas-seguras-en-mysql-con-php

Comment: Realice esas modificaciones, tambien cambie la colocacion de la BD a ``utf8mb4_general_ci`` y tambien a ``utf8_general_ci`` pero sigue sin funcionar :/

Comment: Perdón, olvidé pasar el primer parámetro a `mysqli_real_escape_string()`. Primero hay que pasar la conexión y luego el campo.

Answer (score 1):

La base de datos debe ser utf8mb4.
Pero PHP no sabe si la base de datos está en utf8mb4, enviará la información con cualquier tipo de conjunto de carácteres a la base de datos.
Para que PHP sepa el conjunto de carácteres usado por la base de datos, debajo de la conexión se le indica el set_charset que usa la base de datos, si es conexión por PDO:

```
$conexión->set_charset('utf8mb4');
```

y si es por función mysqli:

```
mysqli_set_charset($conexion, 'utf8mb4');
```